# Make it easier to get to Teams from the public sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

Firstly, [Stack Overflow's contact page](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact) identifies that this community is where feedback should be shared.

> To share product feedback on our products, please [visit our community here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) .

With that said, I find it notably difficult to log in to Stack Overflow for Teams.

On the main SO website (https://stackoverflow.com), there isn't any link that takes you to the actual Teams product itself (https://stackoverflowteams.com).

While there is an option under the "Products" menu, it only takes you to an informational site related to teams (https://stackoverflow.co/teams/).

This informational website for Teams oddly doesn't have any link to the actual product.

If one attempts to Google something like "[stackoverflow teams login](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20teams%20login)", you are presented with links to the informational website, which in turn has no link to the product itself.

Broadly speaking, it is unusually difficult to find the login for Stack Overflow for Teams.

I propose putting a "Sign-in" button on the Teams informational website, next to the "Get Started" button (which is only for creating new accounts).

Comment: Stack Overflow gives their Teams Support Portal link as [this shortened URL](https://s.tk/support). Given that you're a current Teams customer, I'd suggest creating a ticket there. It is currently unclear what level of support Stack Overflow is intending to offer via questions and answers here on Meta Stack Overflow. For existing Stack Overflow for Teams Enterprise and Business customers, we've been explicitly directed to close support questions and direct users to the above Support Portal. We've asked what to do about everything else, but haven't gotten an answer from Stack Overflow, yet.

Comment: As to a link to Teams, there's been other questions asking for a *bit* more connectivity between Teams and SE/SO. So far, all that's been provided is the link to https://stackoverflowteams.com/ available in the popup shown when you click "Looking for your Teams?" at the bottom of the left-sidebar, which is an improvement over no link at all, but still isn't good. [To be clear, I'm not saying that's all that should be available, just that even though hidden, it is available and that having that is slightly better than no link at all, which is what it was for a while.]

Comment: The "Looking for your Teams?" sidebar item would only appear assuming a user shares the same email across both products (Teams and the main Stack Overflow site). I feel it is a safe assumption that the majority of Teams users, use their organization/business email address, and their personal email for the main Stack Overflow site.

Comment: It's also strange that the link in the Products menu is still stackoverflow.co**m**/teams (which redirects to stackoverflow.co/teams).